# using getdate() in sql server to get date as "27Aug13"?

Tags: sql-server, getdate

Query to get the below as output is required.

How can I get ouput as **27AUG13** in SQL SEVER?

Please suggest

Comment: Do you mean 28Aug13? It's the 28th here, and already the 29th in Australia.

Answer (score 0):

The following will have spaces:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),6)
```

You can replace spaces:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),6),' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but the following works:

```
  SELECT replace(convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 6), ' ', '')
```

The internal `convert(varchar, getdate(), 6)` returns (at least, today) "28 Aug 13", with the `replace` then removing the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (works also in SQL-Server 2005 without `DATE`):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(),6) AS [TodaysDate]
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6595/0)</kbd>   `28 Aug 13`